# Word or phrase for warming your eye after accidentally poking your eye

Tags: word-usage, american-english, spoken-english

A person accidentally poked his eye with his finger. So he had to warm his eye by covering his eyes with a cloth that was warmed(cloth) by bringing it close to the mouth and breathing on it:

So what is to be used?(while telling someone how to do it)

> **A cloth has to be warmed by bringing it close to your mouth and warming it with your breath** and then do the warm compress.

Is there a shorter way to express the bold line that sounds more natural in everyday English?

Answer (score 2):

Not everybody is trained in first aid and so I would personally be hesitant to over-simplify an instruction like this.

The noun "compress" meaning a lint pad pressed on to part of the body is fairly well recognised, so if your statement was for an audience you believe would have some knowledge of first aid or would not require too much explanation you could simply say:

> Place a warm compress over the eye.

You might want to specify a "warm *dry* compress" as some people might expect a compress to be dampened with water.

If you feel further instruction is necessary then I don't see how you can make your statement much shorter, but it probably reads better if you said:

> Place a warm, dry compress over the eye. You can warm a clean cloth with your breath.

You could remove the terminology "compress" by saying:

> Warm a clean, dry cloth with your breath and then place the warmed cloth over the eye.